# Integral representation of Bessel function $J_0$

Tags: integration, analysis, bessel-functions

In *Table of integrals, series and product* by Gradshteyn and Ryzhlik I find the following identity, which I should use in my calculation:

> $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\sin\left(z \cdot\mathrm{ch}x\right)dx=\frac    {\pi}{2}J_0(z), \ \ \Re(z)>0$

How to prove it ? I tried check that this integral satisfies differential equation for Bessel function, but there is a problem with convergence of integrals which are obtained by differentiation of given integral.

Comment: May I ask what is meant by "ch$x$"?

Comment: $\mathrm{ch}x\equiv \mathrm{cosh}x$

Comment: What definition of the Bessel function will you accept as 'the main definition'? Is it only differential equation, as you tried? Or will another integral definition will be ok? What about series?

Comment: Series and integral representations, given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function - section "Bessel's integrals," are acceptable. I don't remember if I had proved other representations - It was few months ago, I must find my notes with these calculations. This integral appeared when I did calculations in field theory - I tried to solve some distributional equation and in cited book I found that integral which I need expressed through the Bessel function.